# Bad substitution using awk

Tags: bash, vim, awk

I am trying to open some files as `awk`'s output; the command is:

```
grep "formatDate\s=" "js/components/" | awk '{print $1}' |  awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $1}'
```

and it (seems to) work correctly.

If I try to open that output as vim's tabs, like this:

```
vim -p ${ grep "formatDate\s=" "js/components/" | awk '{print $1}' |  awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $1}' }
```

then I get:

> -bash: ${ grep "formatDate\s=" "js/components/" | awk '{print $1}' |  awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $1}' }: bad substitution

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not send the output of the pipeline to a file and then open that file?

Comment: Not sure I am getting your point: if I would open that file, I would get to edit it as text (text as filenames list).
Do you mean I should cat the file and open the cat's output? But in that case would be the same output as awk.
Sorry if I am just misunderstanding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to execute a command is `$()`, whereas you are using `${}`.

Hence, this should work:

```
vim -p $(grep "formatDate\s=" "js/components/" | awk '{print $1}' |  awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $1}')
```

Comment: Argh... Thanks! Really embarrassing, I need holidays... :(